# udf input/output error

Tags: osx, windows, compatibility, bunsenlabs, udf

A few months ago I formatted half an ssd (for use by all of my operating systems as file storage, I use os x, Debian, and Microsoft's windows) 
It was recommended that I use `udf`, because it is, in most cases, compatible with the operating systems in question. However, I later began getting input output error messages, even when using a file manager to open the drive.

```
rizk@rizk-bl-h:/media/rizk/LinuxUDF/torrents$ ls
ls: cannot access 'legal_software.dmg': Input/output error
```

The command then proceeds to list the rest of the files and directories in the folder. I figure, at least I have my files, but when trying to open them it always reads `Failed to open directory "LinuxUDF". when getting information for file "/media/rizk/LinuxUDF/kj1WRC3.jpg": Input/output error.` Leaving my files un-browsed. However I can open things such as torrent files through my torrent client, I cannot access anything outside of it, and the files in question seem corrupt and broken (for example videos play half through then stop playing entirely).

Any ideas?

edit: per request, here is the results of `smartctl --all`
https://pastebin.com/GP2a9Gng

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se].  **;-)** Could you [edit] your question and add the output to `smartctl --all /dev/XdY` where `X` and `Y` denominate your SSD and then ping me @Fabby?

Comment: Before voting to close, please give feedback.

Comment: @Fabby i added a past bin link where you can see the results. thank you!

Comment: It's not a hardware error, but I know too little of UDF to help you any further. *Sorry!*